# error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = '9'' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update a product with the following information, but I'm receiving an error about the "where id"

```
<?php
function alteraProduto($conexao, $id, $nome, $preco, $descricao, $categoria_id, $usado) {
    $produtos = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $produto);     
    $query = "UPDATE produtos SET nome = '{$nome}', preco = {$preco}, descricao = '{$descricao}', categoria_id = {$categoria_id}, usado = {$usado} WHERE id = '{$id}'";
    return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$usado`?

Answer (score 2):

`usado` column probably contains strings and you are inserting one so you need to surround with quotes

```
usado = '{$usado}'
```

So the query will look like that

```
UPDATE produtos 
SET nome = '{$nome}', preco = {$preco}, descricao = '{$descricao}', categoria_id = {$categoria_id}, usado = '{$usado}' 
WHERE id = '{$id}'
```

Integer columns only don't need to be surrounded with quotes